# Django modifying admin edit interface

Tags: django, admin

So here is my admin.py

```
class ContentPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (("category", "listing_title1", "show_listing1"),)
```

the category is ManyToMany fields, listing_title1 is CharField, and show_listing1 is a BooleanField.

Now it will display all of them in one line, but I want to put the show_listing1 below the listing_title1. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you can make that specific change, I think you will have to write the entire page for managing the ContentPageAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps fieldsets will allow you to do what you want:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

```
class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'sites')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('registration_required', 'template_name'),
        }),
    )
```